# Rotate and move UIView simultaneously and set its center point

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, core-graphics, quartz-2d

I'm making a game which uses multiple UIViews for its displaying of content.

There are 2 UIViews. One of which is a map; another is a plane.
The plane's view is static. It doesn't move, rotate, scale etc.
I'd like to have the map translating under the plane, rotating at the same time. The map's origin (or center point) needs to be set as the plane's center point every frame.

How do I achieve this?

I'm using CGAffineTransform for this, and it works okay, until I want to turn round back on the map once I've left it.

Here's what I'm doing now:

```
CGAffineTransform oldTransformation = CGAffineTransformTranslate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0, frames);
oldTransformation = CGAffineTransformRotate(oldTransformation, rotation);
cityView.transform = oldTransformation;
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: have you found a solution to this ?

Answer (score 0):

This blog [here](http://blog.corywiles.com/using-caanimationgroup-for-view-animations) talks about using CAAnimationGroup to apply multiple animations (center point, rotation, and bounds) at the same time. It includes a sample application which you can get on github [here](https://github.com/kwylez/UIView-GroupAnimations). (Note: run the app in iPad simulator).

The animation used in that project combines the simultaneous change of center point and rotation of a view.

Hope this helps.